# Android - shared_prefs missing items

Tags: android

I'm confused by the way preferences seem to work in Android.

In my Android Studio project I have an xml file containing all my preferences:

app/src/main/res/xml/system_preferences.xml

In my main activity I call the following to fetch preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

`prefs.mMap` contains only some of the preferences from system_preferences.xml, why would some be missing?

Using ADB shell I see /data/data/com.my.app/shared_prefs/com.my.app_preferences.xml which contains the same subset of preferences.

How do I find my missing preferences?

**UPDATE**: my system_preferences.xml is actually a PreferenceScreen xml file.

Comment: use getSharedPrefereces() instead of PreferenceManager

Comment: this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values